# Passing variables and functions through fakeroot

Tags: bash, shell-script, fakeroot

I want to use fakeroot for a project, but the project has lots of functions and variables that I need to pass through to fakeroot.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
myVar="foo"

function testFunction() {
    echo "$myVar"
}

fakeroot -- bash -c testFunction
```

but it doesn't run `testFunction` or echo out `myVar`

Comment: This is a false problem: `fakeroot` isn't causing this. You could remove `fakeroot` and you'd get the problem simply with `bash -c testFunction`. So it probably falls into https://xyproblem.info/ category. You're trying to solve with Y, what's the actual X? Anyway, you can run your whole script with fakeroot outside of it to solve this (and also remove bash -c of course)

Comment: Then how does `makepkg` do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
myVar="foo"

function testFunction() {
    echo "$myVar"
}

tmp_function=$(declare -f testFunction)
fakeroot -- bash -c "$tmp_function; testFunction"
```

Comment: You'd also need to include the output of `declare -p myVar` to propagate that variable's definition to the `bash` shell started by `fakeroot`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `bash`'s exported function feature. However, given that `fakeroot` is an `sh` script, you'd need to be on a system where the `sh` implementation doesn't strip those `BASH_FUNC_fname%%` variables from the environment like `dash` does. To make sure it doesn't happen you could have `fakeroot` interpreted by `bash` itself as `bash -o posix` which is a `sh` interpreter.

```
#!/bin/bash -
myVar="foo"

testFunction() {
    printf '%s\n' "$myVar"
}

export myVar
export -f testFunction

fakeroot=$(command -v fakeroot)
bash -o posix -- "${fakeroot:?fakeroot not found}" -- bash -c testFunction
```

Note that you also need to export `myVar` for that to be available to the `bash` started by `fakeroot`. Instead of calling `export` for both `myVar` and `testFunction`, you could also issue a `set -o allexport` before declaring them.